# Measure distance between two arrays of vectorized word counts in Python

Tags: arrays, dataframe, numpy, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a dataframe with  a column which is a result from vectorization of tokens (words of sentence after tokenization) and the this  column consists of array from different dimension, and I want to compute the similarity between  all these arrays in the dataframe and the input array which is from different dimension too, how Can I do that in python?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`scikit-learn` implements many distance functions that can [measure how similar two arrays are](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#pairwise-metrics). For many NLP problems, people start with [cosine similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity), which just measured the angle between two vectors.

`scipy` also implements [some of the same and some additional metrics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) which could work for your problem.

You'll want to look at a few options for your problem and see what works best.